# go-pg - reading the ID returned after the upsert

Tags: postgresql, go, upsert, go-pg

I've created an upsert like this in go-pg:

```
db.Model(myModel).Returning("id").
OnConflict("(fieldA) DO UPDATE set fieldB=EXCLUDED.fieldB").Insert()
```

and now I'd like to read the returned id. How would I do that? All the examples I've seen ignore the result returned by the insert/update queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from the [example](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-pg/pg#ex-DB-Insert-OnConflictDoUpdate), the ID will be in `myModel`.

```
myModel := &MyModel{
    FieldA: `Something something something`
}

_, err := db.Model(myModel).
    OnConflict("(fieldA) DO UPDATE").
    Set("fieldB = EXCLUDED.fieldB").
    Insert()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(myModel.Id)
```

Looking at the Postgres log, it is doing `insert into ... returning "id"` to get the ID.

Comment: No, the ID doesn't end up in the model. How would it know that it needs to update the ID, not some other field, anyway?

Comment: @kozyr Maybe because it's the primary key. Works For Me™. Did you try it?

Comment: @kozyr Looking at the Postgres log, it is running `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING "id"`.

Comment: My bad, had another issue with UUIDs here, but now it works with them as well.

Comment: if you do any edit to your answer, I'll be able to vote it up - otherwise Stackoverflow locks that.

Comment: @kozyr Done. Thanks.